# AngularJS :KB-focus not working on first element of md-list if first element is deleted

Tags: angularjs

I am using this library for keyboard events and focus on md-list-item,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-keyboard

I am using kb-focus for focus on md list

In the controller, I am calling kbfocus(observation.observationId) after the list is refreshed.

where observationId is the first element of the list.

When I delete first element of the list, the focus doesn't come on the first item of the list. The focus does come on the first item when a non first element is deleted. I have checked that the observationId is of the first element of the newly returned list.

Any suggestions?

Following is the html code:

```
 <md-list flex kb-list>
        <md-list-item
                ng-repeat="notification in vm.notificationsOb track by 
                notification.notificationId"
                ng-click="vm.eventHandler($event)"
                md-ink-ripple="false"
                style="padding: 0px; "
                ng-class="$index % 2 == 0 && 'evenrow' || 'oddrow'"
                kb-item="notification"
                kb-focus="notification-{{notification.notificationId}}"
                ng-keydown="vm.onKeyDown($event, notification, $index)">
            {{notification.subjectId}} 
         <div class="delete_Check">
                <md-checkbox md-no-ink ng-model="notification.selected" aria-invalid=true aria-label="checkbox"
                             checklist-value="notification.rno" ng-change="vm.isLabelChecked(notification)"
                             class="notification-checkbox" id="{{'div' + notification.notificationId}}">
                </md-checkbox>
         </div>  
        </md-list-item>
 </md-list>
```

Following is the code at controller:
deleteNotification() is called when a checkbox is selected and delete button (which is on top of the md-list) is clicked. vm.arrOfNotificationId contains the array of Ids to be deleted.

```
     function deleteNotification() {
        notificationService.deleteSelectedNotifications(vm.arrOfNotificationId,
            PortalService.getUserNameFromQueryString(), fetchNotificationList);
    }

 function fetchNotificationList() {

        notificationService.getNotificationListData(PortalService.getUserNameFromQueryString(),
            PortalService.getListLimit(),PortalService.getSecurityToken(), onGetListSuccess);
    }

    function onGetListSuccess(list) {
        vm.notificationsOb = list;
            if (vm.selectedItem == null) {
                vm.selectedItem = _.first(list);
            }
            /* jshint ignore:end */
            if (vm.selectedItem !== null) {
                kbFocus.set('notification-' + vm.selectedItem.notificationId);
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this question makes sense.  "When I delete the first element of the list, the focus doesn't come on the first item of the list."  How could it?  You can't focus on something that doesn't exist because it's been deleted?  Maybe I just don't understand what you are trying to accomplish? (no code doesn't help that any either).

Comment: After the element is deleted ,the list is reloaded. I mean when the first item is deleted and the list is reloaded thereafter, the focus doesn't reappear on the list. This is not the case if I delete any other element in the list. I hope the problem is more clear.

Comment: The only thing that would clarify the problem is a [mcve]

Comment: I have added some snippets. Please see if it helps to give a better picture.